# Show dialog form not in modal mode

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have dialog form. To call it from my application I use code:

```
BOOL CpointMFC2App::InitInstance()
{
    CWinApp::InitInstance();
    Dialog dlg1;
    dlg1.txt= "NotificationText";
    int r= dlg.DoModal();
        return r;
}
```

And now I don't wont to have modal mode - I would like to let program go without waiting user input. How to make my dlg1 show in non modal mode?

Dialog form:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "pointMFC2.h"
#include "Dialog.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"


// Dialog dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(Dialog, CDialogEx)

Dialog::Dialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(Dialog::IDD, pParent)
{

}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
}

void Dialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Dialog, CDialogEx)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &Dialog::OnBnClickedOk)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// Dialog message handlers
BOOL Dialog::OnInitDialog() 
{
        CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
        SetWindowText(txt);
        return TRUE;
}

void Dialog::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}
```

Comment: search about *modeless dialog*...

Comment: Even if you change the dialog to modeless, you can't let the dialog hang about when `CpointMFC2App::InitInstance()` returns because `dlg1` will go out of scope and will be destroyed, so your dialog box will crash

Answer (score 1):

To create a nonmodal dialog you have to call the dialog's Create function. Do this in the constructor of your dialog class. Then you must return TRUE from InitInstance to keep the program running.

```
m_pMainWnd = new Dialog();
return TRUE; // Run MFC message pump
```